# WKWebView change size issue

Tags: ios, wkwebview, nslayoutconstraint, uiviewanimation

I have a controller with WKWebView (its inside a container view because WKWebView can't use before iOS 10).
I want to change the WKWebView's size using animation but when WKWebView's size changed the webpage loaded goes off to view and its not adjust with the new web view size.

this is my code:

this code is the webView's controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = YES;

   NSString *jScript = @"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";
    WKUserScript *wkUScript = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:jScript injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];
    WKWebViewConfiguration *webConfiguration = [WKWebViewConfiguration new];
    WKUserContentController *contentController = [WKUserContentController new];
    [contentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:self.WKWebDataSource.messageString];
    [contentController addUserScript:wkUScript];
    webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
    webConfiguration.userContentController = contentController;

    self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, self.container.frame.size.height) configuration:webConfiguration];
    self.webView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.webView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    [self.container addSubview:self.webView];
    [self addConstraintToWKWebView];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:MGPSafeString(self.WKWebDataSource.urlString)];
    NSURLRequest *requestUrl = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    self.title = self.WKWebDataSource.titleString;
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestUrl];
}

- (void) addConstraintToWKWebView
{
    NSMutableArray <NSLayoutConstraint*> *arrConst = [NSMutableArray <NSLayoutConstraint*> new];

    NSLayoutConstraint *topCons = [self.webView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.container.topAnchor];
    NSLayoutConstraint *trailCons = [self.webView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.container.trailingAnchor];
    NSLayoutConstraint *leadCons = [self.webView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.container.leadingAnchor];
    NSLayoutConstraint *bottomCons = [self.webView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.container.bottomAnchor];

    [arrConst addObject:topCons];
    [arrConst addObject:trailCons];
    [arrConst addObject:leadCons];
    [arrConst addObject:bottomCons];

    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:arrConst];
}
```

this is the code about animation:

```
-(void)viewAnimationWithFrame:(CGRect)frame duration:(CFTimeInterval)duration
{
    CGRect layerNewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    CGRect viewNewFrame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

    self.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    self.container.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]];

    CABasicAnimation *myAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"frame"];

    [self.view.layer setFrame:layerNewFrame];
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:myAnimation forKey:@"AnimationStreamingController4"];

    [self.webView.layer setFrame:layerNewFrame];
    [self.webView.layer addAnimation:myAnimation forKey:@"AnimationStreamingController3"];

    [CATransaction commit];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];

    self.view.frame = viewNewFrame;
    self.container.frame = viewNewFrame;
    self.webView.frame = viewNewFrame;

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

    [self.webView layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.webView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

    [UIView commitAnimations];


    self.webView.scrollView.contentSize = viewNewFrame.size;
}
```

what I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property of webView clipToBounds to true. Your web view's frame is reduced to the size you specified but the content is not clipped. So you need to clip the content as.

```
self.webView.clipToBounds = true
```

Comment: I tried to do: self.webView.clipsToBounds = YES; but it doesn't work

Comment: You are using the propety masksToBounds which cause the clipToBounds to not work please remove masksToBounds and use clipToBounds

Comment: Ok do one thing set          self.setNeedsDisplay()
. It will redraw all the views. Do it after changing the frame. Also use the clipToBounds propetry.

Comment: I have to call on view or web view?

Comment: On main view. If It  doesn't work then do it for all view

Comment: I did it. I added it for every view before [UIView commitAnimations]; but it doesent work

Comment: Ok i will do it and send the code to you. Please let me know is it the complete code ?

Comment: what do you need?

Comment: the code is above, if you want create a controller and put it inside